# Jetty: How could I use FilterHolder to "monitor" incoming HTTP POST request contents?

Tags: java, http, servlets, post, jetty

I tried to do...

### Source

```
FilterHolder myHolder
    = new FilterHolder(new Filter() {
        public void init(FilterConfig fc) throws ServletException {
        }

        public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp,
                FilterChain fc) throws IOException, ServletException {
            HttpServletRequest httpReq = (HttpServletRequest) req;
            HttpServletResponse httpResp = (HttpServletResponse) resp;

            // HERE:
            InputStream is = httpReq.getInputStream();
            // (read is to a string and output it, works,
            // but swallows all data forever)

            fc.doFilter(httpReq, httpResp);
        }

        public void destroy() {
        }
    });
```

... but swallows all data and real servlets don't get anything.

I just want to "read" **POST request** contents and output them for debugging.

*NOTE 1: I don't want to "intercept" requests, they should go through as before.*

*NOTE 2: An additional hint, how to do the same with **POST responses** would be very kind.*

**EDIT** Replaced `Reader` with `InputStream`. `Reader` didn't work at all.

Comment: @Maurício Linhares   -- `Reader` caused the exception, replaced by `InputStream`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it! I'm using a wrapper for InputStream and OutputStream each.
**Tested. Works for both directions.**

### HttpRequestCopyFilter

```
final class HttpRequestCopyFilter implements Filter {

private final OutputStream copyOutput;

public HttpRequestCopyFilter(OutputStream copyOutput) {
    this.copyOutput = copyOutput;
}

public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {
}

public void destroy() {
}

private void flushCopy() throws IOException {
    copyOutput.flush();
}

public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp,
        FilterChain fc) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest httpReq = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    HttpServletResponse httpResp = (HttpServletResponse) resp;

    HttpServletRequestWrapper requestWrapper =
            new HttpServletRequestWrapper(httpReq) {

                @Override
                public ServletInputStream getInputStream()
                        throws IOException {
                    final ServletInputStream original =
                            super.getInputStream();

                    return new ServletInputStream() {

                        @Override
                        public int read() throws IOException {
                            int c = original.read();
                            if (c >= 0) {
                                copyOutput.write(c);
                                flushCopy();
                            }
                            return c;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public int read(byte[] b) throws IOException {
                            int count = original.read(b);
                            if (count >= 0) {
                                copyOutput.write(b, 0, count);
                                flushCopy();
                            }
                            return count;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public int read(byte[] b, int off, int len)
                                throws IOException {
                            int count = original.read(b, off, len);
                            if (count >= 0) {
                                copyOutput.write(b, off, count);
                                flushCopy();
                            }
                            return count;
                        }
                    };
                }
            };

    fc.doFilter(requestWrapper, httpResp);
}
}
```

### HttpResponseCopyFilter

```
final class HttpResponseCopyFilter implements Filter {

private final OutputStream copyOutput;

public HttpResponseCopyFilter(OutputStream copyOutput) {
    this.copyOutput = copyOutput;
}

public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {
}

public void destroy() {
}

public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp,
        FilterChain fc) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest httpReq = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    HttpServletResponse httpResp = (HttpServletResponse) resp;

    HttpServletResponseWrapper responseWrapper =
            new HttpServletResponseWrapper(httpResp) {

                @Override
                public ServletOutputStream getOutputStream()
                        throws IOException {
                    final ServletOutputStream original =
                            super.getOutputStream();
                    return new ServletOutputStream() {

                        @Override
                        public void write(int b) throws IOException {
                            original.write(b);
                            copyOutput.write(b);
                            flush();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void write(byte[] b) throws IOException {
                            original.write(b);
                            copyOutput.write(b);
                            flush();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void write(byte[] b, int off, int len)
                                throws IOException {
                            original.write(b, off, len);
                            copyOutput.write(b, off, len);
                            flush();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void flush() throws IOException {
                            original.flush();
                            copyOutput.flush();
                            super.flush();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void close() throws IOException {
                            original.close();
                            copyOutput.flush(); // DON'T CLOSE COPY-OUTPUT !!!
                            super.close();
                        }
                    };
                }
            };

    fc.doFilter(httpReq, responseWrapper);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Servlet specification states that `getInputStream` *may* interfere with e.g. `getParameter(String name)`, see [this](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter%28java.lang.String%29). So after calling `getInputStream` you may not be able to use the request objects' 'higher level' functions.

You could configure [Jetty's request logging](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Configure_Request_Logs) and use logback together with [`TeeFilter`](http://logback.qos.ch/access.html#teeFilter). It seems to implement the behaviour you need (did never use it).

Answer (score 0):

Given posts store their key=value pairs in the body which may be read using an InputStream, the very act of you reading the InputStream may consume it, meaning the IS is empty when the real servlet tries to check it.